# Can I select a multi-dimensional HTML array in JavaScript as a multi-dimensional array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays

If I have the following HTML on a page:

```
<input type="hidden" name=item[0][id]>
<input type="text"   name=item[0][title]>
<input type="text"   name=item[0][description]>

<input type="hidden" name=item[1][id]>
<input type="text"   name=item[1][title]>
<input type="text"   name=item[1][description]>

<input type="hidden" name=item[2][id]>
<input type="text"   name=item[2][title]>
<input type="text"   name=item[2][description]>
```

I would like to select the items using JavaScript (or JQuery) in such a way that I can loop over the items using the outer array.

Currently I have the following JQuery/JavaScript to handle the items:

```
var items = ($('[name*="item["]'));
var i = 0;

while (i < items.length) {

    if (items[i++].value === '') {
        // No ID set.
    }
    else if (items[i++].value === '') {
        // No title set.
    }
    else if (items[i++].value === '') {
        // No description set.
    }
}
```

Is there a way to select the elements so that I can loop over them using notation more like the following (Where items.length is 3)?

```
for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    if (items[i][0].value === '') {
        // No ID set.
    }
    else if (items[i][1].value === '') {
        // No title set.
    }
    else if (items[i][2].value === '') {
        // No description set.
    }
}
```

Or even more like this?

```
for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    if (items[i].id.value === '') {
        // No ID set.
    }
    else if (items[i].title.value === '') {
        // No title set.
    }
    else if (items[i].description.value === '') {
        // No description set.
    }
}
```

Or would this require more manipulation and processing to go from selecting from the DOM to creating the data structure to loop over?

Comment: There is no "HTML array." Those are just individual inputs. The seeming array handling you see server-side is a feature of your server-side environment, nothing more. Yes, you could certainly write a general purpose function that you passed a set of elements to which would parse the `name` and populate an array of objects. But you'll have to write it, there's nothing built in.

Comment: Maybe you can work out something with classes, adding `class="0 id"` to your html and later select it with `document.querySelector(".0.id")`, but working with classes this way may overload a bit your page and maybe it's not the best way to proceed

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I suspected this might be the case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18155277/how-would-i-dynamically-convert-form-fields-to-multi-dimensional-js-object) is exactly what you are looking for (which is not really related to selectors):

```js
function serialize () {
    var serialized = {};
    $("[name]").each(function () {
        var name = $(this).attr('name');
        var value = $(this).val();

        var nameBits = name.split('[');
        var previousRef = serialized;
        for(var i = 0, l = nameBits.length; i < l;  i++) {
            var nameBit = nameBits[i].replace(']', '');
            if(!previousRef[nameBit]) {
                previousRef[nameBit] = {};
            }
            if(i != nameBits.length - 1) {
                previousRef = previousRef[nameBit];
            } else if(i == nameBits.length - 1) {
                previousRef[nameBit] = value;
            }
        }
    });
    return serialized;
}

console.log(serialize());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="hidden" name=item[0][id]>
<input type="text"   name=item[0][title]>
<input type="text"   name=item[0][description]>

<input type="hidden" name=item[1][id]>
<input type="text"   name=item[1][title]>
<input type="text"   name=item[1][description]>

<input type="hidden" name=item[2][id]>
<input type="text"   name=item[2][title]>
<input type="text"   name=item[2][description]>
```

See the related [JSFiddle sample](http://jsfiddle.net/w4Wqh/2/).

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way to add a custom function into JQuery to get the data structure you're looking for.

```
$.fn.getMultiArray = function() {
    var $items = [];
    var index = 0;
    $(this).each(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        if ($this.attr('name').indexOf('item[' + index + ']') !== 0)
            index++;
        if (!$items[index])
            $items[index] = {};
        var key = $this.attr('name').replace('item[' + index + '][', '').replace(']', '');
        $items[index][key] = $this;
    });
    return $items;
};

var $items = $('input[name^="item["]').getMultiArray();
```

This allows you to have the references in your "ideal" example.

```
var $items = $('input[name^="item["]').getMultiArray();
$items[0].id;
```

JS Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/apphffus/